# EU Blue card in Switzerland

Tags: blue-card, switzerland, poland

I currently have EU Blue Card issued in Poland.
I have a job offer from Switzerland and I wonder, what will the consequences if I accept it, assuming my work permit in Switzerland was approved and I have it:

1. Is it correct, that I will have to re-apply for Blue Card in Switzerland. There is a separate work permit at CH, how is it related to Blue Card? Can my Blue Card be prolonged in this way?
2. If I will have to move to another country in future, will I be able to use this Blue Card? Meaning, whether it will remain active and will I be able to come back to Poland?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Switzerland is not an EU member, it is not a part of the Blue Card program. That means it has its own system of residence and work permits that is entirely incompatible with that of the EU, except for the fact that the actual residence permit cards are very similar in appearance.